# Handle URL response from another app

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I try to handle URL response from another app in my app.
I check URL in AppDelegate with this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
```

I should get response:

> com.myApp://response?state=OK

but I got only

> com.myApp

string from this method after return from another app.

How should I define URL types in myApp - Info - URL Types? Have to I define URL response in URLScheme or in URLIdentifier?
And what is the best way how to handle URL response, which I get from another app?

Comment: Need to see your code. Questions aren't clear, what do you mean by "URL response from other app"? Be more specific.

Comment: how the other app calls your app ? pls update your question!

Comment: Assuming you're just using `UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL:` then you're probably just not accessing the components of the `NSURL` correctly.  Did you try logging its `absoluteString` property?  As others have stated, sharing your code would probably get you an actual answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! @Charles A., your answer really help me :) I rewrite url.scheme  to url.absoluteString and I got all URL response, which I have needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just seeing the URL scheme, then you're probably not accessing the correct property on `NSURL`.  There are various properties that you can use to get the different parts of the URL, which you can see in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW21).  If you just want the full URL in string form, you should try the `absoluteString` property.